# How to loop through a rows in a data frame, keeping a tally of how many columns are greater than value in row in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, count

Can someone help me with the below please?

I have merged a dataframe and got the min value for each column of the data frame, 1005 columns with a min value. This is now in a data frame in a single row.

I want to loop a dataframe I have made for last seasons football stats, keeping a tally of how many stats the a team(row) is greater than the value in the min data frame.

df is the data frame with min values for each row

leagueTwo is the data frame with the stats want to loop through and keep a tally of how many stats the teams are greater than the min value

```
a = dfl2.min(numeric_only=True)
   
df = pd.DataFrame([a])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
( dfl2 < df.T[dfl2.columns].values ).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. Appreciated.

The dfl2 data frame has extra columns that I don't want to check vs df due to be strings etc. I have tried to add inplace=False but hasn't worked. Is there a way to only check columns mapped in each frame and just ignore the ones dfl12. Just want to count the ones that are in both.

Comment: ```KeyError: "None of [Index(['id', 'name', 'cleanName', 'english_name', 'shortHand', 'country',\n       'continent', 'founded', 'image', 'flag_element',\n       ...\n       'name_ru', 'name_es', 'name_se', 'name_de', 'name_zht', 'name_nl',\n       'name_it', 'women', 'parent_url', 'prediction_risk'],\n      dtype='object', length=1057)] are in the [columns]"